# done button only for numberpad keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am working on the iPhone application. I have four textfields in one of the view. In these four textfield I have one textfield in which there will be use of numberpad keyboard. But on numberpad keyboard there is no return key. So I have added "Done"button programmatically by using following code.

```
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self                  
            selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];        
} else {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
}

   - (void)addButtonToKeyboard {
// create custom button
UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53);
doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.0) {
    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneUp3.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneDown3.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
} else {        
    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneUp.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneDown.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
[doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
// locate keyboard view
UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
UIView* keyboard;
for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
    keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    // keyboard found, add the button
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
        if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
                               [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];                
    } else {
        if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
                   [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        }
     }
    }

     - (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
// if clause is just an additional precaution, you could also dismiss it
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 3.2) {

        [self addButtonToKeyboard];


}
  }

       - (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note {
// if clause is just an additional precaution, you could also dismiss it
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {

        [self addButtonToKeyboard];


      }
   }


- (void)doneButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"doneButton");
    NSLog(@"Input: %@", contactno.text);

    [contactno resignFirstResponder];

     }
```

It is fine for this particular textfield. But this button is also get add for the rest of the textfields. How could unhide this button for other textfields. 
                                [image]

thanks alot in advance.

Comment: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/amkeyboardnumberpad take a look at this implementation, works very well for me

Comment: this is a really terrible thing to be doing. It can easily break if the implementation of the keyboard ever changes. It doesn't work on iPads, and it especially doesn't work with the split keyboard in iOS 5.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Please please please please please please please please please please please please please do not do this.**  This is so ridiculously fragile.  Consider this:

- what if the layout of the number keypad changes?
- what if the colors of the keys change?
- what if the implementation of the keyboard changes such that it's no longer the window at index 1?
- what if the implementation of the keyboard and peripheral host change such that introspecting the description breaks?
- what if you're running this on iPad where the keyboard has a totally different layout?

These are just a couple of the myriad of problems that come with glomming your UI into private view hierarchies.

## DON'T DO THIS.

Here are 2 alternatives instead:

1. Use the `-inputAccessoryView` property on every `UIResponder` (and thus every `UIView`) to define a `UIToolbar` with a "Done" button.  The `inputAccessoryView` will be positioned above the keyboard as the keyboard animates in and out.
2. Add a transparent `UIView` over your entire UI that captures tap events and causes the keyboard to dismiss

Comment: 3. File a bug report asking Apple to add a freaking Done button to the number pad already.

Comment: @Maulik convince your client there are better ways to do it

Comment: For the inputAccessoryView  option, see an example here: http://iosinfopot.blogspot.com/2013/09/uitoolbar-above-keyboard-for-uitextview.html

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could keep a global variable `UITextField * selectedTextField` as a pointer (weak reference) to the textField the user currently has selected. Also store `IBOutlets` to all the `UITextField` object on your view (strong references). Then wrap the entire `addButtonToKeyboard` body in a big if clause:

```
if (self.selectedTextField == self.contactNumberTextField){
    // ... add button
}
```

You'll need to set up the `UITextField` delegate method

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

to know which textField is the currently selected one.

In fact I think you could even do it without the outlets, using `selectedTextField.keyboardType` property, but then again, you'll probably already have the outlets anyway since you need them to read user input from them.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your project and just set iboutlet of text field.It have some unused methods too but you can get your choice of done button using that.Then you will remove unused methods.This is just for Get Done button on number pad keyboard

.H file

```
@interface aaaViewController : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UITextField *txthello;
UIImage *numberPadDoneImageNormal;
UIImage *numberPadDoneImageHighlighted;
UIButton *numberPadDoneButton;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *numberPadDoneImageNormal;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *numberPadDoneImageHighlighted;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *numberPadDoneButton;
```

.M File

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

// Add listener for keyboard display events
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification 
                                               object:nil];     
} else {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                               object:nil];
}

// Add listener for all text fields starting to be edited
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(textFieldDidBeginEditing:)
                                             name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification 
                                           object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification 
                                                  object:nil];      
} else {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                                  object:nil];
}
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification 
                                              object:nil];
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (UIView *)findFirstResponderUnder:(UIView *)root {
if (root.isFirstResponder)
    return root;    
for (UIView *subView in root.subviews) {
    UIView *firstResponder = [self findFirstResponderUnder:subView];        
    if (firstResponder != nil)
        return firstResponder;
}
return nil;
}

- (UITextField *)findFirstResponderTextField {
UIResponder *firstResponder = [self findFirstResponderUnder:[self.view window]];
if (![firstResponder isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    return nil;
return (UITextField *)firstResponder;
}

- (void)updateKeyboardButtonFor:(UITextField *)textField {

// Remove any previous button
[self.numberPadDoneButton removeFromSuperview];
self.numberPadDoneButton = nil;

// Does the text field use a number pad?
if (textField.keyboardType != UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad)
    return;

// If there's no keyboard yet, don't do anything
if ([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] count] < 2)
    return;
UIWindow *keyboardWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];

// Create new custom button
self.numberPadDoneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.numberPadDoneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53);
self.numberPadDoneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = FALSE;
[self.numberPadDoneButton setTitle:@"Return" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//  [self.numberPadDoneButton setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18]];
[self.numberPadDoneButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:77.0f/255.0f green:84.0f/255.0f blue:98.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  

[self.numberPadDoneButton setImage:self.numberPadDoneImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.numberPadDoneButton setImage:self.numberPadDoneImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.numberPadDoneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(numberPadDoneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Locate keyboard view and add button
NSString *keyboardPrefix = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2 ? @"<UIPeripheralHost" : @"<UIKeyboard";
for (UIView *subView in keyboardWindow.subviews) {
    if ([[subView description] hasPrefix:keyboardPrefix]) {
        [subView addSubview:self.numberPadDoneButton];
        [self.numberPadDoneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(numberPadDoneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        break;
    }
}
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)note {
[self updateKeyboardButtonFor:[note object]];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
[self updateKeyboardButtonFor:[self findFirstResponderTextField]];
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note {
[self updateKeyboardButtonFor:[self findFirstResponderTextField]];
}

- (IBAction)numberPadDoneButton:(id)sender {
UITextField *textField = [self findFirstResponderTextField];
[textField resignFirstResponder];
}


- (void)dealloc {
[numberPadDoneImageNormal release];
[numberPadDoneImageHighlighted release];
[numberPadDoneButton release];
[super dealloc];
}
```