# trying to add done button to Numeric keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to add a "done" button to the UIKeyboadnumpad, but with no success.
What's wrong in my code?

the keyboard don't have the done button

```
@implementation DemoViewController

- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];

    textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 26)];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    textField.text = @"12345";
    [self.view addSubview:textField];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {  
    // create custom button
    UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53);
    doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneUp.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneDown.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // locate keyboard view
    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0];
    UIView* keyboard;
    for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        // keyboard view found; add the custom button to it
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
                [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        } else {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
                [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        }

    }
}

- (void)doneButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Input: %@", textField.text);
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [textField release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: Seems your code tags didn't work.

Comment: Your code example wasn't displaying correctly, but it got fixed up by a kind volunteer, nevermind. :)

Comment: Maybe it's duplicating http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584538/how-to-show-button-done-on-number-pad-on-iphone.

Comment: I have found this code over the internet and tried to fix it and make it work with no success, help me if you have any cluew what is the problem

Comment: its not duplicate, its another problem

Comment: Which part doesn't work? Be more specific. Is the button visible? Is it visible but not working? Have you set breakpoints to see which parts of your code are executing?

Comment: done button is not being added to the keyboard

Comment: Before you try and do this, please take note of the reasons against this sort of customisation in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8246080/41116

Comment: Please see this link. Its very much easy and self explanatory.
https://github.com/SunilSpaceo/SKInputClass

Hope i am helpful to you.

Answer (score 24):

**Another solution. Perfect if there are other non-number pad text fields on the screen.**

[image: inputAccessoryView]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelNumberPad)],
                         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Apply" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneWithNumberPad)],
                     nil];
    [numberToolbar sizeToFit];
    numberTextField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
}

-(void)cancelNumberPad{
    [numberTextField resignFirstResponder];
    numberTextField.text = @"";
}

-(void)doneWithNumberPad{
    NSString *numberFromTheKeyboard = numberTextField.text;
    [numberTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

I needed the phone pad (with the +*#)  and not the number pad, do I didn't even had the empty button in the corner.

Comment: What if I have a few numbers field and I want to know who was the sender?

Comment: @Dejel, make each number field an instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

Write your add button's code in 
`- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note`

instead of

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note
```

For this implement `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` notification like :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) 
                                                     name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

I think `UIView* keyboard;` is not getting the keyboard's view as keyboard is not displayed yet, it will display !!!

Answer (score 1):

Some of the tutorials are incomplete or are much older. This tutorial works from IOS 4.3 onwards and I checked it. Save the two image graphics, and paste in the code. There is very little to change. Here is the link.

ps. I am not affiliated in any way with this article, but found it to be complete.

http://www.neoos.ch/blog/37-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key

Answer (score 0):

To make it short: take a screenshot, cut out the whole backspace key, flip it horizotally, clear its backspace symbol in Photoshop and overlay it with the text that we want on our **return** key. We’ve chosen to label it **DONE**.
Now we have the image for our custom button’s UIControlStateNormal.
Repeat the whole procedure (with a touched backspace key when taking the screenshot) to get a second image for our button’s `UIControlStateHighlighted`.

Here’s the result: <*missing image*>

---

Now back to coding:
First we need to know when the number pad is going to slide up on the screen so that we can plug our custom button before that happens.
Luckily there’s a notification for exactly that purpose and registering for it is as easy as:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

*Don't forget to remove the observer from the notification center in the appropriate place once you're done with the whole thing*:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Now we’re getting to the heart of it. All we have to do in the `keyboardWillShow` method is to locate the keyboard view and add our button to it.
The keyboard view is part of a second UIWindow of our application as others have already figured out (see this thread).
So we take a reference to that window (it will be the second window in most cases, so `objectAtIndex:1` in the code below is fine), traverse its view hierarchy until we find the keyboard and add the button to its lower left:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {  
    // create custom button
    UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53);
    doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneUp.png"]
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneDown.png"]
                forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // locate keyboard view
    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]
                                                               objectAtIndex:1];
    UIView* keyboard;
    for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        // keyboard view found; add the custom button to it
        if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"UIKeyboard"] == YES)
            [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
    }
}
```

Voilà, that’s it!
The empty space for our button starts at coordinate (0, 163) and has the dimensions (106, 53).
The `doneButton` method has to be written now of course, but that’s not hard any more.  Just make sure that you call `resignFirstResponder` on the text field that is being edited to have the keyboard slide down.

We’re “DONE”.