# UINumberPad with Done button

Tags: keyboard, ios7, uitextfield

I have been struggling with this since iOS3, is there still no way to easily add a done button to a number pad for a UITextField?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no simple way still provided by apple. You need to customize keyboard on run time by your own.  You can refer this useful link http://www.neoos.ch/blog/37-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key to create done button on numberpad.

You can try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079815/trying-to-add-done-button-to-numeric-keyboard) as well.

Comment: Thank you. I will attempt these solutions.