# Number Pad done button disappearing

Tags: iphone, ios7, keyboard, uitextfield

[image]

When I set done button on Number pad keyboard it is working before ios 7 but not working in the ios 7 and later.

It is disappearing for double tap /copy/paste etc events on uitextfiled.

Any help?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: I added done button on NumberPad keyboard. It is showing and working. but when I double tab on uitextfiled or long pressed then it is hiding  in IOS 7.

Comment: Please check below link it has same problem which i am facing, but i dont want to go any alternative solution:         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239273/done-button-only-for-numberpad-keyboard

Comment: Can you provide some code?